# Terraform azurerm_api_management_api bumping revision does not apply all required changes

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

We are managing our API Management platform in Azure with terraform. Sometimes we need to bump the revision, and when we do that there are several issues:

1. The API that gets bumped is recreated (expected)
2. The recreated API is lost from all products it belonged to
3. The recreated API does not get any policies applied

So when the revision is bumped, the pipeline has to be run twice:

1. The API is recreated
2. The API is added to the product again and gets its policy applied

This is how the template looks like:

```
# Fetch existing API management instance
data "azurerm_api_management" "storemanager_api_management" {
  name                = local.api_management_name
  resource_group_name = local.api_management_resource_group_name
}

# Create the API
resource "azurerm_api_management_api" "api" {

  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.storemanager_api_management.name
  resource_group_name = local.api_management_resource_group_name

  name         = "api"
  path         = "api"
  display_name = "api 1"
  protocols    = ["https"]
  revision     = var.api_revision
  subscription_required = true

  subscription_key_parameter_names {
    header = local.api_subscription_key_name
    query = local.api_subscription_key_name
  }

  import {
    content_format = "swagger-link-json"
    content_value  =  format("https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s/%s",
      data.azurerm_storage_account.storage_account.name,
      data.azurerm_storage_container.open_api_definition_storage_container.name,
      var.api_api_version,
      local.api_api_definition_name
    )
  }
}

# Create the product
resource "azurerm_api_management_product" "product" {
  
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.storemanager_api_management.name
  resource_group_name = local.api_management_resource_group_name

  product_id = "product"
  display_name = "Product"
  description = "Collection of APIs"
  subscription_required = true
  subscriptions_limit = 1
  approval_required = true
  published = true
}

# Associate the API with the product
resource "azurerm_api_management_product_api" "product_api" {

  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.storemanager_api_management.name
  resource_group_name = local.api_management_resource_group_name

  product_id = azurerm_api_management_product.product.product_id
  api_name = azurerm_api_management_api.api.name
}

# Apply policy to the API
resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "policy" {
  api_name            = azurerm_api_management_api.api.name
  api_management_name = data.azurerm_api_management.storemanager_api_management.name
  resource_group_name = local.api_management_resource_group_name

  xml_content = templatefile("./policy.tmpl", { x_functions_key_value = var.function_key, backend_name = azurerm_api_management_backend.generic_function_app_backend.name })
}
```

Is  this a bug, or am I not using terraform correctly? How do I re-add the recreated API to the product and get its policy applied in *one* run of the pipeline?

Comment: Is everything applied in one run, if you start from scratch? Can you also share, how do you define ````data "azurerm_api`_management"````?

Comment: @FedorPetrov Unfortunately I cannot remove the product since we have subscriptions tied to it and I would force all developers to acquire new keys. But deleting the APIs and running from there I see the APIs get created, added to the already existing product and have their policies applied. I get the result that I want if the APIs do not exist at all before running

Comment: I updated the terraform snippet with the data section

Comment: Apparently this is an issue in many other resources. I found this https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/8099#issuecomment-313551316

Comment: Seems legit. I've seen guys in this link tried to use depends_on explicitly and it didn't help. Maybe some kind of workaround would be to provide if allowed ````triggers = {...}```` to ````resource "azurerm_api_management_api_policy" "policy" {...}````. triggers should depend e.g. on the parameter with which the stuff recreation is triggered.

Comment: I didn't find a way to solve this, the workarounds others have used did not trigger any updates for me. But while searching for a solution I realized we are using revisions the wrong way and should actually use version sets. We'll see if I run into the same issues there.

Comment: perhaps you should try with setting dependencies explicitly by using "depends_on"